# Python C++ extension - memory leak or access violation

Tags: python, c++, memory-leaks, access-violation

I've written a Python C++ extension, however I have a problem with one of its functions.
The function provided by this extension takes 2 arrays as inputs and produces one as an output.

I've only left the relevant part of function's code

```
float* forward(float* input, float* kernels, npy_intp* input_dims, npy_intp* kernels_dims){

    float* output = new float[output_size];

    //some irrelevant matrix operation code

    return output;
}
```

And the wrapper:

```
static PyObject *module_forward(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject *input_obj, *kernels_obj;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "OO", &input_obj, &kernels_obj))
        return NULL;

    PyObject *input_array = PyArray_FROM_OTF(input_obj, NPY_FLOAT, NPY_IN_ARRAY);
    PyObject *kernels_array = PyArray_FROM_OTF(kernels_obj, NPY_FLOAT, NPY_IN_ARRAY);

    if (input_array == NULL || kernels_array == NULL) {
        Py_XDECREF(input_array);
        Py_XDECREF(kernels_array);
        return NULL;
    }


    float *input = (float*)PyArray_DATA(input_array);
    float *kernels = (float*)PyArray_DATA(kernels_array);

    npy_intp *input_dims = PyArray_DIMS(input_array);
    npy_intp *kernels_dims = PyArray_DIMS(kernels_array);

    /////////THE ACTUAL FUNCTION
    float* output = forward(input, kernels, input_dims, kernels_dims);


    Py_DECREF(input_array);
    Py_DECREF(kernels_array);

    npy_intp output_dims[4] = {input_dims[0], input_dims[1]-kernels_dims[0]+1, input_dims[2]-kernels_dims[1]+1, kernels_dims[3]};

    PyObject* ret_output = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(4, output_dims, NPY_FLOAT, output);

    delete output;//<-----THE PROBLEMATIC LINE////////////////////////////

    PyObject *ret = Py_BuildValue("O", ret_output);

    Py_DECREF(ret_output);

    return ret;
}
```

The delete operator that I highlighted is where the magic happens: without it this function leaks memory, with it it crashes because of memory access violation.

The fun thing is I wrote another method, that returns two arrays. So the function returns a float** pointing to two float* elements:

```
float** gradients = backward(input, kernels, grads, input_dims, kernel_dims, PyArray_DIMS(grads_array));

Py_DECREF(input_array);
Py_DECREF(kernels_array);
Py_DECREF(grads_array);

PyObject* ret_g_input = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(4, input_dims, NPY_FLOAT, gradients[0]);
PyObject* ret_g_kernels = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(4, kernel_dims, NPY_FLOAT, gradients[1]);

delete gradients[0];
delete gradients[1];
delete gradients;

PyObject* ret_list = PyList_New(0);

PyList_Append(ret_list, ret_g_input);
PyList_Append(ret_list, ret_g_kernels);

PyObject *ret = Py_BuildValue("O", ret_list);

Py_DECREF(ret_g_input);
Py_DECREF(ret_g_kernels);

return ret;
```

Notice that the second example works flawlessly, no crashes or memory leaks, while still calling `delete` on arrays after they have been built into PyArray objects.

Could someone enlighten me about what's going on in here?

Answer (score 3):

From the `PyArray_SimpleNewFromData` [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/c-api.array.html#c.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData):

> Create an array **wrapper** around data pointed to by the given pointer.

If you create an array with `PyArray_SimpleNewFromData`, it's going to create a wrapper around the data you give it, rather than making a copy. That means the data it wraps has to outlive the array. `delete`-ing the data violates that.

You have several options:

- You could create the array differently so you don't just make a wrapper around the original data.
- You could carefully control access to the array and make sure its lifetime ends before you `delete` the data.
- You could create a Python object that owns the data and will `delete` the data when the object's lifetime ends, and set the array's `base` to that object with [`PyArray_SetBaseObject`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/c-api.array.html#c.PyArray_SetBaseObject), so the array keeps the owner object alive until the array itself dies.

Comment: I thought it works that way, but the second example disagrees. I delete the pointers there as well, and for some reason everything works.

Comment: @Lugi: Undefined behavior is not required to crash. C++ is not a nice language. Do not think that code is correct simply because it seems to run without crashing.

Comment: So an array created for example by using method `PyArray_Zeros` and then filled with desired values from C array and the one created with `PyArray_SimpleNewFromData` are not going to behave identically?

Comment: @Lugi: Correct. An array created with `PyArray_Zeros` will own its data and delete the data when the array's lifetime ends. An array created by `PyArray_SimpleNewFromData` will not own its data, and you must ensure that the array's data outlives it.

Comment: What defines data ownership? Isn't it just something like a one flag that can be changed?

Comment: @Lugi: While there is an [`OWNDATA` flag](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flags.html), you can't just fiddle with the flag to change ownership. We're getting beyond the scope of the question here; if you want to know more, you should read the NumPy docs, or the code if you want to dig deeper than what the docs document.

Comment: One more question: I guess the good solution to this situation will be, as you said, `PyArray_SetBaseObject`. Is it going to work like this: `PyObject* owner; PyArray_SetBaseObject(array, owner);`